# Safer aproach than shell-escape to solve problem

Tags: shell-escape

I have a folder of files which follows this naming convention: "<id>-<name>". I need to refer to them from a latex document, but "<name>" often changes, so i need to do so using only "<id>.

I have managed to do this by enabling `shell-escape` and using `\input{|"<command>"}`, to run a shell command which gets the full filename from an id. It works, but enabling `shell-escape` concerns me, because this system does, from time to time, compile files that i have not made, and have not read.

Can anyone think of a better solution, or is it somehow possible to make enabling `shell-escape` safe?

Comment: It is much safer to do `ls > filelist.txt` first and then read that from tex (or `dir` if you are on windows).  or you can use texosquery to get a file list without using (full) shell escape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a file list using `ls` (or `dir` in windows) and pass it to tex, but if you need to do it within tex then `texosquery` is allowed to run by default so:

With a test subdirectory of the current directory with three files

```
$ ls testdir
a-b.txt  a-c.txt  z-a.txt
```

this document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{texosquery}
\begin{document}

\TeXOSQueryRegularFileList\zzz{,}{testdir}
\show\zzz

\end{document}
```

produces terminal output of

```
$ pdflatex dd124
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./dd124.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-08-07>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/texosquery/texosquery.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/texosquery/texosquery.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/texosquery/texosquery.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def)
(./dd124.aux) (|texosquery-jre8 -ir , testdir )
> \zzz=macro:
->a-b.txt,a-c.txt,z-a.txt.
l.6 \show\zzz
             
?
```

so `\zzz` is the comma separated list of filenames, replace `\show` by whatever loop over that list you need to do.

Comment: I tried installing it, and it's working. I will have to build a solution around it, but i doubt that  that will be a problem. Do you know how it works? Does it access a tex interface or something safe or whats going on?

Comment: @aaaaaaaaaa it's a java program that has been tested to be safe and obey the tex security settings such as as paranoid etc from `texmf.cnf` so it is allowed (like makeindex) in the default "restricted shell escape" list so it can be run without using `--shell-escape` although called via `\write18` see `texdoc texosquery`